# Trouble importing class from the appEngine package

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine

This is my first try at server-client interactions for an android app. I wrote this MainActivity.java file for a little app i'm trying to make. I'm trying to implement the Google App Engine Database to store information for markers on a map. I'm basing my addMarkerTask class off of this sample from google.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-shopping-assistant-backend-java/blob/master/MobileAssistant-Tutorial/Phase1_Snippets/MainActivity.01.java

and here is my class

```
package com.example.rpialmanac;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;


import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GoogleMap mMap;
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    final LatLng FIELD = new LatLng(42.730357, -73.679951);
    Marker field = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(FIELD));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
   * AsyncTask for adding a new marker to the database  */
private class addMarkerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    /**
     * Calls appropriate CloudEndpoint to add a new marker to the database.
     *
     * @param params the place where the user is adding a marker
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      addMarker newMarker = new addMarker();

      // Set the ID of the store where the user is. 
      // This would be replaced by the actual ID in the final version of the code. 
      newMarker.setMarkerName("86 field");
      newMarker.setMarkerType("recreation")
      newMarker.setMarkerLat(42.730357);
      newMarker.setMarkerLong(-73.679951);

      addMarkerEndpoint.Builder builder = new addMarkerEndpoint.Builder(
          AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
          null);

      builder = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(builder);

      Checkinendpoint endpoint = builder.build();


      try {
        endpoint.insertCheckIn(checkin).execute();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return null;

}
}
```

}

However, eclipse is unable to resolve the object addMarker which I know is because I haven't imported the class from my addMarker.java file which is located in my rpiAlmanac-AppEngine package, but eclipse does not recognize the class when I start typing com.example.rpiAlmanac.*. Does anyone know if it's possible to import a class from another package? If there is another way to go about doing this, I would be happy to hear any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add it to your import statements.

```
import com.example.rpiAlmanac.addMarker;
```

Note that by convention, you should make a classname start with an uppercase letter.   i.e. Addmarker

By the way, do you have Auto Activation for content assist enabled?  Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor  -> Content Assist

Also check if your class is in your build path.  Project -> properties -> Java Build Pathh -> source

Comment: Thank you! I got it to recognize the other package. The only error I'm still having is eclipse cannot resolve      Addmarkerendpoint.Builder (I changed the naming convention) The sample from google uses the same line for their Checkin class, so I'm not sure where I am getting the error from

Comment: @Alex Check the package and classname from the sample carefully.  For example, MainActivity has "import com.google.samplesolutions.mobileassistant.checkinendpoint.Checkinendpoint;" but I only see com.google.samplesolutions.mobileassistant.CheckInEndpoint in the actual src.  Maybe their sample is outdated.

Comment: I noticed that as well. I wasn't sure if I was missing something or if google was actually missing a class in the repository. I will continue looking into it.